# Apache2, Git, Capistrano & Rails - creating symlinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I'm sort of stuck with adding symlinks to my app on the server.  I currently have the following in .gitignore:

/non-public/system/uploads/*

I basically don't want Git to store the contents of the upload directory.  So far so good.

On my server, inside my deploy.rb, I have the following:

```
namespace :customs do
  task :symlink, :roles => :app do
    run <<-CMD
      ln -nfs #{shared_path}/system/uploads #{release_path}/non-public/system/uploads
    CMD
  end
end

after "deploy:symlink","customs:symlink"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"
```

I want to create a symlink after each deployment for the uploads directory, but I keep getting a failed error message because the non-public/system/uploads directory doesn't exist in the git repository in the first place.

I've verified this by taking a look at the repository, and the structure /non-public/system/uploads doesn't exist because I have that set in .gitignore to ignore it.

I've looked at the Git wiki and it doesn't track directories, so I must be missing something.  How do other developers symlink the uploads directory with their server?

Comment: Well, now I'm seeing deployment recipes with commands to mkdir.  Is that what I'm missing?  A command to simply create the directory before symlinking to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'll usually do on my cap deploys is to create the directories, by doing a basic

```
set :deploy_to, "/this/dir"

run "mkdir -p #{deploy_to}/then/more/dirs"

after "deploy:symlink"

namespace :deploy....
  ....
  ....
```

then provide the `run` code to do some symlinks either on an `after` or whatever. This probably not optimal for all situations, but for the simple stuff it usually gets the job done.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  The only issue I'm having now is that I think I did my symlink wrong.  I used the following command -- ln -nfs shared/system/uploads current/non-public/system/uploads -- unfortunately it created a uploads directory inside of the already existing uploads directory. :(

Comment: I fiddled with deploy a bit more and now I understand symlinking and how it needs to be structured.  Thanks for the guidance!